# Десктопное приложение из angular2+node.js

Tags: node.js, angular2

Есть веб приложение, сделанное на angular2 + Node.js. Нужно сделать из него десктопное приложение, знаю, что есть различные фреймворки для написания десктопов на JS, но как можно сделать из уже готового на связке angular2 + Node.js?

Comment: В электрон его https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Спасибо, а чем это решение лучше NW.js?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Зато у тебя уже 2 варианта есть :)

Comment: Technical Differences Between Electron and NW.js
https://electron.atom.io/docs/development/atom-shell-vs-node-webkit/
Я лично выбрал электрон потому что он, как мне кажется, гораздо ближе идеологически к ангуляру и человеческому разуму вообще, а еще он намного быстрее фиксится и обновляется.